# Create a generic validator to prevent newline characters getting added during paste of data in text area + Angular 8

Tags: angular, customvalidator

I would like to create a custom validator that would be able to **detect and remove any newline at the end of the text** in text fields, without being *implicitly* called on those components.

It would be able to detect any text fields and **automatically** implement the validator logic when the page loads.

I know I can simply validate each individual text field but it numbers in 100s and hence would like to know an elegant approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by two methods:
One by having an interceptor and second by having a custom directive for some specific fields which on blur i.e., when the mouse moves away from a field trims the data

Answer (score 0):

I solve similar problems by extends FormControl to map result value.
Now you can use TextControl and validate it with standard angular validators.

```js
import { FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class TypedFormControl<T> extends FormControl {
  constructor(value?: T | null | undefined, validators?: ValidatorFn[]) {
    super(value, validators?.map(TypedFormControl.serializeValidator));
  }

  private static serializeValidator(validator: ValidatorFn): ValidatorFn {
    return (ctrl) =>
      validator({
        value: (ctrl as TypedFormControl<any>).getValue(),
      } as FormControl);
  }

  getValue(): T {
    return this.value;
  }

  update(value: T): void {
    this.patchValue(value);
  }
}

export class TextControl extends TypedFormControl<string> {
  constructor(initialValue: string = '', validators: ValidatorFn[] = []) {
    super(initialValue, [...validators, Validators.maxLength(250)]);
  }

  getValue(): string {
    return `${this.value ?? ''}`.trim();
  }
}
```

To update view

```html
<textarea [formControl]="textControl" (blur)="textControl.update(textControl.getValue())"></textarea>
```